# TypScript Class Generics and Polymorphic attributes

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm having difficulty with Generics & Polymorphic attributes. Am I doing something crazy?

I've stripped down this code pretty far. I have two (or more) classes (`WelcomeTemplate` & `AddToAccountTemplate`) that extend a base class (`TemplateContext`). Each implement their own shape of shape of `context`. The goal is when `EmailService` when initialized, it will take in the name of the template and typescript will be aware of what context is therefor needed given the template.

For example:

```js
new EmailService("WelcomeTemplate", {
    signupUrl: 'https://test.com',
});
```

However within `EmailService` when initializing the template I get the following two TypeScript errors which have me scratching my head. I've fiddled with several approaches, but keep landing back at these errors.

`Argument of type 'AddToAccountContext | WelcomeContext' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AddToAccountContext & WelcomeContext'.`

and

`AddToAccountTemplate' is assignable to the constraint of type 'Template', but 'Template' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'AddToAccountTemplate | WelcomeTemplate'.`

Naturally `AddToAccountContext | WelcomeContext` and `AddToAccountContext & WelcomeContext` conflict. But I'm not certain why typescript is concluding `&` given I'm doing `Templates[Key]` which from generics which I believe should have the types for just at `Key` not a merged type for all Keys.

Is there just a better way to organize subclasses for this scenario?

Here is a [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIBUIFsAOAbOSAHgGEB7cCADzAD5kBvAWAChlkoI4ATCvAT2QIKkGgH4AXMnKUaAblYBfVqzD8cKTLgKQZosMgC8jRQpYICAZ0vIt+QimDbsEcDYzZ7xOzoh7qdIys7DgArgBGeMAIQiIBRiZmyiyq6igAgtzc6GTpCMKh4P40CcxsyHhkAOagAKpQeFKWYFCgVWbsiAXgAHJwWBBNLW1JZhZw1siZ2bn5ZIVgPg7IAa7cNkuQQeXCIM1QoQhgZFAAFLv6UtM5ed1gxWAAlNvs7JahGmePHa9gABbASwAOgu8WMoPkwWQyShYUi0VisjAVyyNzmCweSRULDUGmQAHUIHhhAMHqUoZZgFUQB96o1kPsRkoxlYbITiWQBpsUKsQOtbJ5fC9EftDsczhDkQSiSS-HEaM8yq8GR9oKdvlD2P9ASD5QZwXqfjDynCojFJVJ2bLMUpsbtmshINoHDZjAB5cIAKwgRyBME4EAAXhBTkrpRyuYKHAAaKHXWZ3bmxliKDUpHFpAXOyCux1pMgwR1RnNmVjjSYAUSwcGAeAAytAAG7RCBEKEAaQggl5-IA1l2C1mvBBLMn2NyVjQ1u49mA4CAkOg0kRuZYANqd-gAXVoY+kesnkD5G2LEDXACJJeet8n6GGncO+gMpJufhb90jS+UH74pNyv+w9otGKJynD+DhPoMyCbtGiKXB++iKpqjoAsC4GQJBCToRAkE-FqqG6kiCSSgBrxAUOvgkKyWGnuu2poaekFbnhKE6thCQgBAADuFEOFREyWGBBGSmm7DJMarCcTxVY1vWTYtqc55WpyEDcuesFhm8VI0jgdJSAA5H8YBgDglgSAA9OZOZgLqWD6cmqZAA). It may be simpler to fiddle with there.

Thanks for taking a look with me!

---

```js
interface ITemplate<Context> {
  readonly context?: Context;
}
type TemplateContext = {};
class Template implements ITemplate<TemplateContext> {
  public context = {};
}
```

```js
type AddToAccountContext = {
  loginUrl: string;
  accountName: string;
};
class AddToAccountTemplate extends Template {
  constructor(context: AddToAccountContext) {
    super();
    this.context = context;
  }

  public context: AddToAccountContext;
}
```

```js
type WelcomeContext = {
  signupUrl: string;
};
class WelcomeTemplate extends Template {
  constructor(context: WelcomeContext) {
    super();
    this.context = context;
  }

  public context: WelcomeContext;
}
```

```js
const templates = Object.freeze({
  WelcomeTemplate,
  AddToAccountTemplate,
});

type Templates = typeof templates;

class EmailService<
  Key extends keyof Templates,
  Template extends InstanceType<Templates[Key]>,
  Context extends Template["context"],
> {
  templateName: Key;
  context: Context;

  template: InstanceType<Templates[Key]>;

  constructor(templateName: Key, context: Context) {
    this.templateName = templateName;
    this.context = context;

    const TemplateClass = templates[this.templateName];
    this.template = new TemplateClass(this.context); // Error: Argument of type 'AddToAccountContext | WelcomeContext' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AddToAccountContext & WelcomeContext'.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the compiler does not follow the *correlation* between the type of `TemplateClass`, the type of `context`, and the type of `this.template`.

---

For ease of discussion I'm going to refactor your code to a version with only one [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter `K` corresponding to the one you call `Key`.  Your `Template` and `Context` type parameters are essentially just aliases for various type functions on `Key`, and having extra type parameters doesn't make the issue any easier to discuss or solve:

```
type TemplateInstances =
  { [K in keyof typeof templates]: InstanceType<typeof templates[K]> };

type TemplateContexts =
  { [K in keyof TemplateInstances]: TemplateInstances[K]['context'] };

class EmailService<K extends keyof TemplateInstances> {
  templateName: K;
  context: TemplateContexts[K];

  template: TemplateInstances[K];

  constructor(templateName: K, context: TemplateContexts[K]) {
    this.templateName = templateName;
    this.context = context;

    const TemplateClass = templates[this.templateName];
    this.template = new TemplateClass(this.context); // error!
    //~~~~~~~~~~~ <-----------------> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  }
}
```

I've defined helper types `TemplateInstances` and `TemplateContexts` to be mappings from `templateName` string literals to the corresponding instance type and context type, so that later we can just say `TemplateInstances[K]` in place of your `Template` type parameter, and `TemplateContexts[K]` in place of your `Context` type parameter.

This version has the same problem as yours: the compiler complains about being given unions instead of the intersections it wanted.  But why?

---

The types of  `TemplateClass`, `context`, and `this.template` are dependent on the generic type parameter `K` which is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types).  And so the compiler sees each of them as themselves being union-like.  For example, it knows that `TemplateClass` is one of two possible constructors, and that `context` is an input suitable for one of these two constructors.  But it loses track of each of the fact that `context` will definitely be suitable for `TemplateClass`.  It worries that maybe `TemplateClass` will be, say, the `AddToAccountTemplate` constructor while `context` will be of type `WelcomeContext`.  The only input that the compiler would definitely see as safe for `TemplateClass` would be an input that *both* possible constructors would definitely accept; that would be the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of possible input types.

This sort of failure to follow correlation has long been one of TypeScript's pain points, and prompted me to file [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).  Prior to TypeScript 4.6, the only way to proceed here would either be to write a lot of redundant code to convince the compiler of type safety (which wouldn't work with generics anyway), or to use [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to tell the compiler not to worry about the type safety it couldn't verify anyway.

Such a type assertion is the simplest answer here; inside the constructor, assert that `TemplateClass` is of the following type:

```
    const TemplateClass = templates[this.templateName] as
      new (c: TemplateContexts[K]) => TemplateInstances[K];
      
    this.template = new TemplateClass(this.context); // okay
```

Now there's no error.  You've essentially taken the job of determining the type of `templates[templateName]` away from the compiler.  Everything works now.  Yes, the compiler couldn't tell the difference if you changed it to something completely broken, like

```
    const TemplateClass = templates[
      Math.random() < 0.5 ? "AddToAccountTemplate" : "WelcomeTemplate"
    ] as new (c: TemplateContexts[K]) => TemplateInstances[K]; // okay
```

so you need to take some care when making type assertions.  But it's simple.

---

TypeScript 4.6 introduced some [improvements to generic indexed access](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-6/#indexed-access-inference-improvements) behavior specifically to deal with correlated union types in a type safe manner (well, relatively, anyway; see [ms/TS#48730](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48730)).

It involves refactoring your types to [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) and indexes into them where things are explicitly represented in terms of a generic key type.  The changes here involves [annotating](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) your `templates` variable to be of such a type.  Here's one way to do it:

```
const _templates = {
  WelcomeTemplate,
  AddToAccountTemplate
};

type TemplateInstances =
  { [K in keyof typeof _templates]: InstanceType<typeof _templates[K]> };

type TemplateContexts =
  { [K in keyof TemplateInstances]: TemplateInstances[K]['context'] };

type TemplateConstructors =
  { readonly [K in keyof TemplateInstances]:
    new (c: TemplateContexts[K]) => TemplateInstances[K] };

const templates: TemplateConstructors = Object.freeze(_templates);
```

Note that in the above, the value of `templates` is the same (I use an intermediate `_templates` variable for ease of typings), but the type of `templates` is represented differently.  It's written explicitly as a mapping from generic key `K` to constructor type `new (c: TemplateContexts[K]) => TemplateInstances[K]`.

Once we do that, the error inside `EmailService`'s constructor just disappears:

```
    this.templateName = templateName;
    this.context = context;
    const TemplateClass = templates[this.templateName];
    this.template = new TemplateClass(this.context); // okay!
```

Hooray! Just to drive the point home that the fix depends on the mapped type representation of `templates`, things break again if we use a structurally identical plain object type:

```
const stillTemplates: {
  readonly WelcomeTemplate: new (x: WelcomeContext) => WelcomeTemplate;
  readonly AddToAccountTemplate: new (x: AddToAccountContext) => AddToAccountTemplate;
} = templates; // okay, it's a structrually identical type, but:

    // later
    const TemplateClass = stillTtemplates[this.templateName];
    this.template = new TemplateClass(this.context); // errors came back!
    //~~~~~~~~~~~ <-----------------> ~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

---

So, there you go.  The compiler isn't clever enough to figure out that what you're doing is safe.  To fix it, you can use a type assertion to power through and suppress errors, or you could refactor your types to give it the hints it needs to see the logic in what you're doing.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAsAFBJLwYhRRIAqEYM5ALsgcSUjAK4BGGAlvFIB7YMwAejJAF48AXwDcRErKJKkjAJ4xkAQQAme6kJ3x4QzqIDCI8ZJmt2SDEIDmfYAFUAThgBcSKEYvdxdFNhIEMwtGADlwCH9A4OBQtQVVNjIKKn1DY1NzUVp6JmQICQhgPSpihhBmPAzHM2AkznhGIS8AChbbf1yjEyirG3LGAEpG8PYoTm0eibDHEkYACz4oADo+8elhUXHl9hVCNRIuXgED-qRB-JHGa0OJY9O1TW0kAHUIDDNIM9bPsHLM+C5gPNvH4AkEQm9jllKD8-gCILVSkhxpVqjQ6HUGqCSC02h0ur0xhJ-L9-kJAZTJtMVgF5hBFsdHOtNjsGftdq9zkh3jNLvxBPzGNTUXSIECjmkmkhQJBYAhkAAFLxCXh0aaCkmSZglerQfYAeW4ACsIB0tgAzLwQCBYCDdInsGlojEmgA0gpI92GhUY3uYgtkS0Vqy0yFDEAAkq1GCBgIgqFJ-XgkABtADSSHcSAA1hANEI7eoY+X1PjSlAALr+ROBFOIagxgA8nwg1aNBOgefrAD4hWFBd28cbmHKJOnM7gc-nCyWyxW483k6noI3J-2N62B7n69mAOQSk-10dR0jkZEAUTAID4GAAymyAG4CCAd-PYqpUFdq3XJMDygEd3VWWsTTiSB-FzDl2Alfw4xnRgoEHMcZkgqcEl3Up9y3dCj0w5kDS8dpOh6PtShg3Dcx9G5xmQqDpwZIj6ymCD2C5bZqOg+J9j45haIQzkNm2CU+QZEjmQOQI8JNSxb3TGscPQnitiEiBaPrUTuPEzSWOQGRgAgAB3BTp2U7oNIlJYkAAegcrEvC1LwAEJMxIJyAD8-P8gKfKQDsAFowvCiLIrCkdAtivzM1ORxhX1ZSkAfJ9Xw-L8dEoNlGB-LEKn-YtSyAoyCLTcDMy02i4L0pDLNlNiMOvbD+2YnCKsPXTMzIijyRq+I4IYhqUOao9OK89QDMGyBBKMkSpts3kZAlGTSJEeSUNSmQtPUmaFviS8KCmkhTIs3oOv7VD2KmKQR2AltCJas4sP07ktP2c7GqU7IbIMuz5Ec5yhCLEANFaxDNskbbsm+NYhCEGAVL27NTqQABZeo1i2LwUz0OluimDskAABi2ABWJAAH4kAAIkDApojjOmkH8OnPRlFmpuOqhvsun7xo46QHvKkDnuI4GEvDBVXrO+JVUQJAACUIDtBBKL1GYDSQAB9PaQUzTnIDjP03sZx443DBCJ0ezc02kedFwLYAStXSttGrfWjIbJtxbbTtuy91GjxHdIZltoybsdt6FzzF23bKzr-e3K78JT9jT3PS9w85GNBaTciyS8OdY6QR0QAJ4AMA0Z3l1KtcxaetNGym-mxDTxShbu0Xk+b7qr216HVP7KBO9Ywv+pL80rRtRh7UdZ1XW9tTIzlxDUvS583y8T9EA7TNfyK3FAMbvv7egM3mSqt7Zro+qGXHpqXjQl7mS0p+uvY9aocn4ubMOrBJA9FGJUgLrYW6TJZIaTvvNHCi03qrABitUBjA9LEmHrDZEu0fbZhgYAiAPVEHTQ+kZL65kfrWWWi-NezJEonGvDrQIz4MBxjHlAxwFcq41xRLSE2Rl-DtylHw5+tge68K9EZPSXCRA8ItsGOMgiKHdA7ncAwQwmajBoSLNReQgzMykeGOBo8EIpWyGlR828sqIAAEKVx0C4J8wAD5vSPswYqp9GpfyvisG+78CF1V6o-cB4xv7VQEV4jOL0gl-0ogA+BQ1gEjWCWNF+kCuJINIQkuaODskQHQSQiSKC1pTR1lglSzCMCsNwfgvJRDZKFMMjhchFlyn-W5IDYGLk3JUHQHNbgCAiyeWIb5OK-lgpRUmRFGKYz-LSxmMKZQGRThAA)

Comment: Absolutely a fantastic write up @jcalz . I appreciate your level of detail, research and care in stepping through the reasoning and subsequent options. Thank you for affirm some of my suspicions and aiding in a deeper understanding. I'm going the mapped types direction and feel pretty good about it. Thanks again!